# Templates and Values in different repos via ArgoCD

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argocd

I'm looking for insights for the following situation...

- I have one ArgoCD application pointing to a Git repo (A), where there's a `values.yaml`;
- I would like to use the Helm templates stored in a different repo (B);

Any suggestions/alternatives on how to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

I think [helm dependency](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency/) can help solve your problem.
In file `Chart.yaml` of repo (A), declares dependency (chart of repo B)

```
# Chart.yaml
dependencies:
- name: chartB
  version: "0.0.1"
  repository: "https://link_to_chart_B"
```

Link references:
https://github.com/argoproj/argocd-example-apps/tree/master/helm-dependency
P/s: You need add repo chart into ArgoCD.

[image]

Comment: Hi @quoc9x, I've considered this option, however it seems that ArgoCD is not able to pull the dependencies automatically, that would require a `helm dependency update`. 

https://kb.novaordis.com/index.php/Helm_Dependencies

Comment: you need to add the repository for it to update properly. Proxy charts are definitely the solution here.

Comment: You need add repo chart into ArgoCD. I edited my answer.

Comment: Awesome @quoc9x, really appreciate your inputs. I'm gonna give a try.

Comment: Awesome @LostJon , really appreciate your inputs. I'm gonna give a try.

Comment: @HutgerHauer Were you able to solve this? 
ArgoCD now supports multipe sources[https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/multiple_sources/], we are trying this but got into different issues.

Answer (score 1):

The way we solved it is by writing a very simple helm plugin
and pass to it the URL where the Helm chart location (chartmuseum in our case) as an env variable

```
server:
 name: server
 config:
   configManagementPlugins: |
       - name: helm-yotpo
         generate:
           command: ["sh", "-c"]
           args: ["helm template --version ${HELM_CHART_VERSION} --repo ${HELM_REPO_URL} --namespace ${NAMESPACE}  $HELM_CHART_NAME --name-template=${HELM_RELEASE_NAME} -f $(pwd)/${HELM_VALUES_FILE} "]
```

you can run the helm command with the flag of --repo

and in the ArgoCD Application yaml you call the new plugin

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
 name: application-test
 namespace: infra
spec:
 destination:
   namespace: infra
   server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
 project: infra
 source:
   path: "helm-values-files/telegraf"
   repoURL: https://github.com/YotpoLtd/argocd-example.git
   targetRevision: HEAD
   plugin:
     name: helm-yotpo
     env:
       - name: HELM_RELEASE_NAME
         value: "telegraf-test"
       - name: HELM_CHART_VERSION
         value: "1.8.18"
       - name: NAMESPACE
         value: "infra"
       - name: HELM_REPO_URL
         value: "https://helm.influxdata.com/"
       - name: HELM_CHART_NAME
         value: "telegraf"
       - name: HELM_VALUES_FILE
         value: "telegraf.yaml"
```

you can read more about it in the following blog
[post](https://medium.com/yotpoengineering/argo-cd-applicationset-and-helm-custom-plugin-challenges-and-solutions-2e23fd495c67)

Comment: I tried this approach, but this wouldn't work for me as I'm using a private repo.
In my understanding, `helm template` from the plugin will not have access to the repositories defined inside argocd.

Comment: Also, I think the plugin need to use the `ARGOCD_ENV_` prefix when accessing those env vars...